# Detect inactivity on touch devices with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been researching and found code that detects inactivity(when the user doesn't touch the screen) after the user goes idle for x amount of time which works perfectly when using the mouse but when I try using this with touch screen devices, it doesn't detect my finger or work. I've added a lot of DOM events such as "**touchstart**", "**touchmove**", "**touchend**", "**touchcancel**" and others but they don't seem to work either. Here is my code

```
var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
      var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 3000); 

      //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
      $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
      });
      $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
      });
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
      idleTime = idleTime + 1;
      if (idleTime > 1) { 
        alert("ok");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Define "inactivity". Is me staring at your page for a while reading and re-reading it without moving the mouse "inactive"?

Comment: yes sorry for a vague question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will adjust the timer (you sayd you want an update every minute but you set you setInterval to 3000 millisec and i will try with this:

```
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
  var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); 

  //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  //Zero the idle timer on touch events.
  $(this).bind('touchstart', function(){
   idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(this).bind('touchmove', function(){
   idleTime = 0;
  });
});

function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime = idleTime + 1;
  if (idleTime > 1) { 
    alert("ok");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code:

`$(this).bind('touchstart touchmove click', function(){
  idleTime = 0;
}`

Comment: I tried dragging my finger across the screen and it didn't work for that but worked when I tap the screen. Why is that?

Comment: your first movement was interpreted by the browser as a swipe (touchmove), while the second was actually a tap (touchstart)

Comment: so is there any way to detect when you drag your finger across the screen?

Comment: Yes it is, here is some usefull information about: https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/

Comment: Just add touchmove in the binding event. I added it.